# Create new DataFrame based on hours range of a column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

My df is:

```
  ordinal id latitude longitude timestamp               epoch       day_of_week
  1.0     38 44.9484  7.7728    2016-06-01 08:18:46.000 1.464769    Wednesday
  2.0     38 44.9503  7.7748    2016-06-01 08:28:05.000 1.464770    Wednesday
  3.0     38 44.9503  7.7748    2016-06-01 08:38:09.000 1.464770    Wednesday
```

I want to create a new df1, df2, df3 based on hours range:
Ex: from `2016-06-01 08:00:00.000` to `2016-06-01 09:00:00.000` (from 8 o clock to 9 o clock) I want to have

```
1.0     38 44.9484  7.7728    2016-06-01 08:18:46.000 1.464769    Wednesday
2.0     38 44.9503  7.7748    2016-06-01 08:28:05.000 1.464770    Wednesday
```

I want to do it for all 24 hours. If it is possible I want to do it by code which can be applied to the whole column or I can do it one by one

Comment: What is the reason that the third row got dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe *why* you want to generate hour-specific slices of the raw data. In general, this would be considered bad practice or not pythonic.

I suggest to group your data based on the hour using `groupby` which allows you to loop through these slices, here the data frames `group`.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iN = 100
data_char = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100)
timestamp = pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24', end='2018-04-25', periods=100)

data = {'data_char': data_char, 'timestamp': timestamp}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

for hour, group in df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.hour):
    print(hour)
    print(group)
```